# Serial Wire Viewer (SWV) debugging configuration is grayed out in STM32CubeIDE with stm32gxx chip

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I want to follow the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eg_GLvLHM1o&ab_channel=STMicroelectronics) to set up the Serial Wire Viewer (SWV), but I am not able to configure the debug configuration, as it is grayed out (like in the picture) and then also the configuration in the SWV Viewers does not appear.

I am using the following system:

```
CubeMX v6.6.0
CubeIDE v1.10.0
STM32Cube FW_G0 v1.5.0
Chip STM32G0xx
```

Does my chip even support this feature or why is it grayed out?

[image: Debugging configuration to setup SWV is grayed out]

*I hope that somebody has a suggestion and I also asked in the STM community: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00001gVSwSSAW/debug-configuration-for-swv-viewer-is-grayed-out*

Comment: Serial Wire Output (SWO) is based on the Instrumentation Trace MacroCell (ITM) available in Cortex-M3/M4/M7 microcontrollers. The STM32G0 is a Cortex-M0+ microcontroller, which does not include ITM. So your microcontroller simply does not support it.